# How to find a specific word in multiple webpages or urls and count it, using Python

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Below is my code. Kindly check & correct me.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ["https://www.tensorflow.org/","https://www.tomordonez.com/"]

the_word = input()

r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

words = soup.find(text=lambda text: text and the_word in text)

print(words)

count = len(words)

print('\nUrl: {}\ncontains {} of word: {}'.format(url, count, the_word))
```

How can I change my code to parse multiple URLs and count how many times a specific word occurs?

Comment: What is your problem? Why is your code not working? What is the expected output? Please fill your question with details.

Comment: i want the count of specific word with passing multiple urls??? how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_list = ["https://www.tensorflow.org/","https://www.tomordonez.com/"]

#the_word = input()
the_word = 'Python'

total_words = []
for url in url_list:
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.lower(), 'lxml')
    words = soup.find_all(text=lambda text: text and the_word.lower() in text)
    count = len(words)
    words_list = [ ele.strip() for ele in words ]
    for word in words:
        total_words.append(word.strip())

    print('\nUrl: {}\ncontains {} of word: {}'.format(url, count, the_word))
    print(words_list)


#print(total_words)
total_count = len(total_words)
```

**Output:**

```
Url: https://www.tensorflow.org/
contains 0 of word: Python
[]

Url: https://www.tomordonez.com/
contains 8 of word: Python
['web scraping with python', 'this is a tutorial on web scraping with python. learn to scrape websites with python and beautifulsoup.', 'python unit testing tutorial', 'this is a tutorial about unit testing in python.', 'pip install ssl module in python is not available', 'troubleshooting ssl module in python is not available', 'python context manager', 'a short tutorial about python context manager: "with" statement.']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` module to find particular text.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ["https://www.tensorflow.org/","https://www.tomordonez.com/"]

the_word ='Tableau'

for url in urls:
 print(url)
 r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
 words = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(the_word))
 print(len(words))
```