# Multiple url check from file

Tags: html, python-3.x, search, cpu-word, fromfile

I would like to ask some help for the next project.
I have a txt file (myurls.txt) with many urls
(around 200).
(http:\url1.com,
Http:\urlblue.com etc etc)

These are different pages.

I would like to check these pages source codes and I wanna found two words for example ‘Easter egg’ and save these webpages in a new txt file(match.txt)

For example :

http:\url1.com -> Easter egg

I’ve tried to use python3 but unsuccessful.

Someone can help me please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+scan+files+for+words+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Did you check that 2 questions? One is about “ “search strings in a text file”, it’s absolutely different and the other one it’s “search text in url” very similar but it’s just a simple url and not multiple url from a txt file.

Comment: So we add "list of URLs" to the search and  find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55177632/how-to-find-a-specific-word-in-multiple-webpages-or-urls-and-count-it-using-pyt

Comment: Reload the question for more dupes